# How to write Selenium webdriver script in Java for drop down of ionic Angular web apps?

Tags: java, angular, selenium-webdriver, ionic-framework

My ionic code is :

```html
<ion-item mode="md" lines="none" class="fluent-textbox" *ngIf="grantedRoles.length > 1">
    <ion-select interface="popover" justify="start" (ionChange)="changeUserRole($event)" placeholder="Sign-in as"
            [selectedText] = "userRole" name="userRole">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let grantedRole of grantedRoles; let i = index " style="color: var(--salt-theme-foreground)"
                [value]="grantedRole" [name]="grantedRole">{{grantedRole}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

In this code `grantedRoles` list is "MANAGER" and "TRAINEE".

And my script is :

```java
try {    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("userRole")));
    dropdown.click();

    WebElement option = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#ion-overlay-1 > ion-select-popover > ion-list > ion-radio-group > ion-item:nth-child(2)")));
       
    // Click the desired option
    option.click();

} finally {
    driver.quit();
}
```

I need to avoid ionic tags in locator, is this possible? I tried locator by using name.
ie :

```java
WebElement option = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("MANAGER")));
```

But it's not working.

##### UPDATE:

This is the error exception I get:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.name: MANAGER (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

This is my dropdown html code:

```html
<ion-item mode="md" lines="none" class="fluent-textbox" *ngIf="grantedRoles.length > 1">
    <ion-select interface="popover" justify="start" (ionChange)="changeUserRole($event)" placeholder="Sign-in as" [selectedText]="userRole" name="userRole">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let grantedRole of grantedRoles; let i = index " style="color: var(--salt-theme-foreground)" [value]="grantedRole" [name]="grantedRole">{{grantedRole}}
        </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

And this my source code generated by using script:

```html
<ion-select _ngcontent-sqi-c185="" interface="popover" justify="start" placeholder="Sign-in as" name="userRole" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-label="Sign-in as" class="md in-item hydrated select-expanded"><ion-select-option _ngcontent-sqi-c185="" style="color: var(--salt-theme-foreground);" role="option" id="ion-selopt-0" class="md hydrated">MANAGER</ion-select-option><ion-select-option _ngcontent-sqi-c185="" style="color: var(--salt-theme-foreground);" role="option" id="ion-selopt-1" class="md hydrated">TRAINEE</ion-select-option>
```

In the above generated source code, name is missing, I thought that is the problem.

Comment: @sulfath: Please, when adding new information, [edit] your question and add it to your question. This helps a lot, especially with larger code snippets. I did that for you this time ;-) Please revise if it's correct what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Given the additional code of the generated output, it is visible that the values `MANAGER` and `TRAINEE` are the text values of the option elements, not properties of those elements. That would explain why your code was not working. Your could try waiting for the element to contain the specific text. As there is not `ExpectedConditions` helper method to wait for an element to be visible with some specific text (or I just did not see it) you could do something like this:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@role='option' and text()='MANAGER']")));
```

The `@role='option` part is not really necessary, but I usually try to narrow down the possible results as much as possible and also this shows the intent that the text value should be present in the option element which makes it easier to understand when reading the code.